# Windows Phone 8/8.1 emulator not working after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-10, windows-phone-8-emulator

After upgrading to Windows 10, the Windows Phone 8 and 8 Update 1 emulators are not working, they are stuck at the message.

[image]

I tried deleting the VMs but still getting the same message. I also tried to repair the emulator installations but still the same problem. Please help.

---update----

I also uninstalled the Emulators, allowed the XDE.exe process through the Firewall and Windows defender, deleted the VMs in Hyper-V, but now am getting the following error messages:

[image]

I click OK and after a while this error comes and the Emulator shuts down.

[image]

Comment: You don't happen to have antivirus installed? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/be73ddc6-4116-4552-aca7-7332a19d4601/windows-phone-emulator-error-code-32775?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: No, I had seen this thread.

Answer (score 1):

That is difficult to say without the access to the computer, but i encountered the same error when updated from the Windows 8 to Windows 10 with the installed emulator. What i did to solve was to completely wipe out the emulator leftovers. I suspect that the migration was not very smoothless, and emulator was not able to detect the old virtual machines properly.

I would suggest you to do the same. Try to uninstall everything emulator-related and then go to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Emulation\Images
```

(or something like that, check both Program Files) and move VMs files to the different place. Then, install the development tools again - should work.

Comment: I tried to run repair of the emulator installations after deleting the VMs. But the emulator gets stuck at loading windows OS and times out, then if I try to re-deploy then I get the memory error.

Comment: Not repair, but completely uninstalling. The memory error is the same?

Comment: When that second error appears if you go to Hyper-V Manager what status the emulator VM has?

Comment: "Stopping" is the status shown. I have to hard-reboot the system then.